A question about the improvement points for the simulation（GMAT)
Sorry for my English. I'm not a native speaker.　I am using a software called GMAT from NASA to conduct various simulations, but I failed this time while trying to move a satellite from low Earth orbit to geostationary orbit, so I would like to hear about improvement points.
First, let me introduce the tabs and parameters I used.
<<spacecraft>>
<Orbit tab>
Epoch format;UTCGeorgian Epoch;01 Jan 2000 11:59:59.999 Coordinate System;EarthMJ2000Eq
State type;Keplarian Elements;(SMA 6718km)(ECC,INC,RAAN,AOP,TA 0)
<Ballistic/Mass>
Spherical(Dry Mass;900kg)
<Tanks>
ChemicalTank1
<Actuators>
ChemicalThruster1
<Power System>
SolarPowerSystem
<<HardWare>>
<Chemical Tank1>;(Fuel mass 450kg)(Fuel Density 1260kg/m^3)(Pressure 5000kPa)(Volume 1m^3)
<Chemical Thruster>;(Mass change→Chemical Tank1 is selected)
<SolarPowerSystem>; default
<<Burns>>
<Impulsive Burn1>;(Delta-V Vector Element1;1.2km/s)(Mass change;Chemical Tank1 is selected and 300 is typed in the Isp section)
<Impulsive Burn2>;(Delta-V Vector Element1;2.5km/s,Element;1km/s)(The Mass Change section is the same as before)
<<Propagators>>
<ELO(renamed)>(Min Step Size;0)(Max Step Size;2160)(Point Masses;Luna is selected)
<Mid(renamed)>(Initial Step size;600sec)(Min step size;0)(Max step size;12500)(Point Masses;Luna and Sun is selected)
<GEO(renamed)>(Initial step size;600sec)(Min step size;0)(Max step size;8640)( point masses;Luna and Sun is selected)

<<<Mission Folder>>>
<Propagate1(appended from Mission Sequence)>(stopping conditions; DefaultSC.Elapsed.Days(parameter) and 2(condition))
<Maneuvr1(Inserted after Propagate1)> we don't have any change here.
<Propagate2(Inserted after Maneuver1)>(DefaultSC.Elapsed.Days(Paramete) and 4(condition)


That's everything. I'm not very familiar with GMAT, and after finishing the tutorial, I tried this simulation. I think there might be many things that are unclear, but I kindly ask for your help.

Welcome to Space Exploration SE! Tell us more! What happened? Did you try to run GMAT? Did you get any error messages? If so, please paste those into your question as well! What kind of "improvement" would you like? The more specific details you can add to your question, the better the answers.

yes, I want to run GMAT. And I tried to do it, and I wanted to set up hohnman transfer orbit, but I couldn't. so, I asked you to give me advice like changing parameters, propagates and so on.

From what I can gleam about your script from the info provided, there are a few components that could be causing the issue, and a few components that may enable you to achieve your LEO->GEO goal.
To start, you define a ChemicalThruster and attach it to the spacecraft, but then use ImpulsiveBurns to conduct the maneuvers. The ImpulsiveBurn action does not utilize any of the properties set in the ChemicalThruster object, but it can access and decrement your ChemicalTank, as you have set up. If you want to use the ChemicalThruster, you would need to define a FiniteBurn that uses your predefined ChemicalThruster. Then to use this, in the mission sequence you would use the sequence:
BeginFiniteBurn YourFiniteBurn
Propagate YourProp(yourSat) {yourStoppingConditions}
EndFiniteBurn YourFiniteBurn

Definitely take a look at the Finite Burn examples in the User Guide or samples directory if you haven't already.
Additionally, I'm assuming based on the magnitude of the Delta-Vs that your ImpulsiveBurn2 is meant to get you to GSO, and when at apogee, the ImpulsiveBurn1 will enter into your GEO orbit. If your script is getting close, but not necessarily achieving the GEO orbit, you should utilize a Differential Corrector (I believe there is a Hohmann example) to conduct the transfer, as it will handle the adjustments to the Delta-Vs for you, rather than solving by hand.
Not sure if you can edit or change the question, but adding your scenario as a script would make debugging a bit easier, but hope these things helped!
